# How to make walk cyclic that keeps moving foward

Tags: animation

I have a walk cycle, that isn't stay still. It's animated moving foward 2 step.
How can I repeat this walk cycle, but the location keeps moving foward for more steps, instead of repeat back to origin.

Comment: check out in the dope sheet, which axis is responsible for the movement and just extend the curve accordingly. if you want best support for your answer and exact help, what to do, it would be the best if you append your .blend file here

Comment: the best would be to create a still walk cycle, but if you want to keep the current walk cycle, as Chris suggests, you could use the Graph Editor and copy paste the existing movement so that it continues on the right axis at the point where it currently stops?